# type test in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm writing an evaluator for a little expression language, but I'm stuck on the `rec` construct.

Trying to define a function that lets you know the type that the parameter has.

This is the language:

```
data Ty = Ty :-> Ty | INT  deriving (Eq,Show)
infixr 9 :->
data Expr = Var Nm  | Lam (Nm,Ty) Expr | App Expr Expr
      | Val Int | Add Expr Expr | If Expr Expr Expr
      | Let Nm Expr Expr
      | Rec Expr        deriving Show
type Nm = String
```

And this the evaluator so far:

```
type Te = [ (Nm, Ty) ]
type En = [ (Nm, Value) ]

ty :: Te -> Expr -> Ty
ty te (Var x) = lookup' x te
ty te (Lam (x,t) e) = t :-> t2
  where
    t2 = ty ((x,t):te) e
ty te (App e1 e2) =
  case t1 of
    t2' :-> t  | t2==t2'   -> t
               | otherwise -> error $ show e1 ++ show e2
    _ -> error $ show "not a function type"
  where
    t1 = ty te e1
    t2 = ty te e2
ty te (Val _) = INT
ty te (Add e1 e2) =
  case (t1, t2) of
    (INT, INT) -> INT
    (INT, _  ) -> error $ show "is not INT type"
    _          -> error $ show e1 ++ "is not INT type"
  where
    t1 = ty te e1
    t2 = ty te e2
ty te (If e e1 e0) =
  case t of
    INT | t1 == t0  -> t1
        | otherwise -> error $ show "different type"
    _ -> error $ show e ++ "is not INT type"
  where
    t = ty te e
    t1 = ty te e1
    t0 = ty te e0
ty en (Let x e1 e2) = ty ((x,t2) : en) e2
                            where
                                t2 = ty en e1
ty te e = error $ show e ++ "type inference is not defined yet"
lookup' x en = case lookup x en of
                  Nothing -> error (x ++ " not defined")
                  Just v  -> v
```

For example, type test of `let`:

```
t1 = Let "z" (Val 1) (Add (Var "z") (Val 2))

ty [] t1
```

> asnwer : INT

`rec` expression is used to define recursive function

This is my test function I want to evaluate:

```
t2 = Rec  (Lam ("f", INT :-> INT) . Lam ("i", INT) $
                If (Var "i")
                    (Var "i" `Add` (App (Var "f") (Var "i" `Add` Val(-1))))
                    (Var "i")     
            )
ty [] t2
```

I've tried to make expression:

```
ty en (Rec (Lam (x,_) e)) = v
                where 
                    v = ty ((x,v):en) e
```

`Rec` tried type test like `let`, but there is an error.

Comment: What does `Rec` mean? Recursive?

Comment: ```rec``` is used to define recursive function. I revised the question and rewritten it!

Answer (score 1):

[I had implemented similar code in the past](https://github.com/realglobe-Inc/hrafnar/blob/74aa9044401890291b0eefeb2ebe491d2685d346/server/Hrafnar/Inferer.hs), so you should refer it. You need not to mind abount license (LICENSE explains everything).

`Rec` symbol is unnecessary to define recursive function. If `Let` and `Var` work correctly, you can define. Example as above deals with environment each scope of function, but even if with global environment only it will work.

[To infer types of `Let` is here](https://github.com/realglobe-Inc/hrafnar/blob/74aa9044401890291b0eefeb2ebe491d2685d346/server/Hrafnar/Inferer.hs#L208-L230). Here, considering mutual recursive function, so using graph module, but don't mind it now. Name bound in `Let` can take multi expressions, though as good as single.

Then, `inferBinds` have be seen simple. It takes `Name` and `Expr` (`Maybe Type` is for type annotation, therefore can forget it), and returns `Type` with `[Constraint]` (they are bundled as `Answer`). This is how to collect constraints.

After you get constraints, it's so easy. [See `solve` function](https://github.com/realglobe-Inc/hrafnar/blob/74aa9044401890291b0eefeb2ebe491d2685d346/server/Hrafnar/Inferer.hs#L351-L364). In here, `solve` decides type of variables recursively by constraints. [See also `unify`](https://github.com/realglobe-Inc/hrafnar/blob/74aa9044401890291b0eefeb2ebe491d2685d346/server/Hrafnar/Inferer.hs#L368-L374) and [`bind`](https://github.com/realglobe-Inc/hrafnar/blob/74aa9044401890291b0eefeb2ebe491d2685d346/server/Hrafnar/Inferer.hs#L384-L387).

I really have to write about substitution, fresh variables and so on, but I'm too tired to explain any more. If you want to know in detail, recommend **strongly** to read [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/tapl/).

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, but it is too difficult for me who is not familiar with Haskell.

Comment: I solved this problem, but I'm not sure if it's right. 
```ty en (rec (Lam binds e)) = v where v = ty (binds:en) e```

Comment: Basic idea is collecting constraints and solving equations. For example, if infer types of `Let "f" (Lam "x" (Var "x")) (App (Var "f") (Int 1))` , we can get constraints `x = a`, `f = x -> x`, `1 = Int`, `f 1 = b` and  `expr = b`. Solve these equation, be derived `expr = Int`. The above is just a little bit complicated this.